# How to consume from partitioned topics in flink?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a flink app that needs to consume from 500+ topics(1 kafka partition per topic). The messages in 500 topics are partitioned by a key range. So keys 1-100 are in topicA, 101-200 are in topicB and so on.This is a stateful application so I want to keep the state size low. How can I ensure messages from each topic are being processed by only a fixed deterministic set of task managers.

```
List<String> topics = Arrays.asList("topic.A","topic.B",...);
KafkaSource<TestEvent> source = KafkaSource.<TestEvent>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
        .setTopics(topics)
        .setGroupId("testconsumer")
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setDeserializer(new TestDeserializationSchema())
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

> messages in 500 topics are partitioned by a key range. So keys 1-100 are in topicA, 101-200 are in topicB and so on.

That's not how Kafka partitions work; you should use one topic with 500 partitions. But Flink can be subscribed to many topics, just as any other Kafka consumer.

> ensure messages from each topic are being processed by only a fixed deterministic set of task managers

The Flink app will form a consumer group, so therefore will automatically distribute itself, where each instance will consume a subset of partitions from the total assigned topic subscription.

Comment: there are good reasons outside of the app to have multiple topics and 1 partition. In this case, do I just have to use 'KafkaSource' and use setTopics(..) as usual and Flink will take care of routing the messages from 1 or more topics to a particular TM?

Comment: What good reasons? You're adding extra load to Zookeeper with more topics. Yes, but if your topics are similarly named, use a pattern, not a list https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#topic-partition-subscription